# Force logged in users to see only logged in pages

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, logout

I have a few simple login pages. I have tried to put a code to the page `login.php` to try if that works. But, it didn't.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

What i trying to do is to hide the `login.php` for logged in users. In other words, when they were in logged in status, they try to visit the `login.php`, the `login.php` will automatically redirect them to a specified logged in page. which means `login.php` page is just available for non logged in users. Here is the code i have in my `login.php` page.

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */
    /* Check Login form submitted */    
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        /* Define username and associated password array */
        $logins = array('Test1' => 'test1','Test2' => 'test2','Test3' => 'test3');

        /* Check and assign submitted Username and Password to new variable */
        $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
        $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

        /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */        
        if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
            /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page  */
            $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$Username; <-- this line amended to display username properly.
            header("location:index.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            /*Unsuccessful attempt: Set error message */
            $msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
<section class="pd">
<div class="login">
<form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form">
    <h1>Login</h1>
      Username:<br/>
      <input name="Username" type="text" class="Input">
      <div class="formgap"></div>
      Password:<br/>
      <input name="Password" type="password" class="Input">
      <div class="formgap"></div>
      <?php if(isset($msg)){?><?php echo $msg;?> 
      <div class="formgap"></div>
      <?php } ?> 
      <div class="formgap"></div>
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="Button3">
</form>
</div><!--login-->
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to visit `login.php` after login. I can still it.
Any suggestions to do it? Thanks!

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION)` your Session and check user data saved or not ?

Comment: @Karan, not sure where to put this line. I'm still new in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check this at `login.php`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username']) && !empty($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

User will be redirected to `index.php` if he is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

This is enough, Try this:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: You might be writing `!empty`

Comment: Yes as per his requirement, it will automatically redirect to index page if the session set ie logged in.

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS, thanks! Your code works well and is simple enough. Can i ask you a simple question?

Comment: I tried to put this code in `index.php` (logged in page) to get username displayed on logged in page. `if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
 header("location:login.php");
 exit;
}`. But, it doesn't work. Because it shows password instead. Any solution?

Comment: In order to display the user name, you can use
 echo !empty($_SESSION['UserData']['Username']) ? $_SESSION['UserData']['Username'] : '';

Comment: Thank you! I tried. But, It is still showing password instead.

Comment: You may have wrongly stored the password in the session username. Try clearing the session and echo.

Comment: Hi Sanjay Kumar N S, thank you so much! Pradeep Singh has helped to solve this issue for me. There was an error in `login.php` page. Now, it working. Thank you for your kind of help! :)

Answer (score 1):

you dint check whether userdata is set or not . try this

```
<?php 
 session_start(); /* Starts the session */
/* Check Login form submitted */    
if(isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
     header("location:im.php");
        exit;
}
elseif(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    /* Define username and associated password array */
    $logins = array('Test1' => 'test1','Test2' => 'test2','Test3' => 'test3');

    /* Check and assign submitted Username and Password to new variable */
    $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
    $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

    /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */        
    if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
        /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page  */
        $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
        header("location:im.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        /*Unsuccessful attempt: Set error message */
        $msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
<section class="pd">
<div class="login">
<form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form">
 <h1>Login</h1>
  Username:<br/>
  <input name="Username" type="text" class="Input">
  <div class="formgap"></div>
  Password:<br/>
  <input name="Password" type="password" class="Input">
  <div class="formgap"></div>
  <?php if(isset($msg)){?><?php echo $msg;?> 
  <div class="formgap"></div>
  <?php } ?> 
  <div class="formgap"></div>
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="Button3">
</form>
</div><!--login-->
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Jornes : its ok bor :). if any doubt in php ask me

Answer (score 0):

If you get session at restricted pages then simply check like this

```
<?php 
     if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
         ?>
        <script>
        window.location='index.php';
        </script>
        <?php
     }
?>
```

Use javascript redirection instead of php header function to redirect.